# Más de dos contadores simultáneos

Tags: javascript, html, bucles, setinterval

Básicamente estoy intentado hacer mas de un contador de forma simultanea.
Es decir :

```
 <div id="time0"></div>
    <div id="time1"></div>
    <div id="time2"></div>
```

---

```
    var cntr1 = 1;
    var x = [300,200,400];
    for (let index = 0; index < x.length; index++) {
        var x = setInterval(function() {
            document.getElementById("time"+index).innerHTML = x[index]+= index;  
        }, 1);
    }
```

Que por cada milisegundo, vaya sumando a cada posición del Array 1 en este caso.
Pero soy incapaz de hacerlo funcionar de esa manera, no sé en que me estoy equivocando.

Comment: estás declarando tu var x dos veces.

Answer (score 1):

Además de estar declarando tu `var x` dos veces cuando estás seleccionando dentro del `setInterval` a tu elemento con id `time0` le estás sumando el valor de `index` que en la primera iteración vale por su puesto 0, entonces todo el tiempo estaría incrementando +0, por otro lado para el ejemplo que muestras puede parecer imperceptible pero cada mili segundo de tu intervalo de tiempo estás haciendo query a tu DOM innecesariamente y eso es considerado mala práctica.
Esta sería la versión adecuado a lo que buscas:

1. Tenemos el array de enteros en `const array`.
2. Luego utilizando querySelectorAll seleccionará todos los elementos del DOM con la etiqueta div y el id que empiece con el prefijo time, es decir `<div id="time0"></div>, <div id="time1"></div> y <div id="time2"></div>` esto nos devuelve un `NodeList` la cual es guardada en la variable `const divs`.
3. Luego se itera esta `NodeList` usando la función `forEach` que por
   cada
       iteración recibe el elemento y su indice en la `NodeList` en la
       función anónima `(div, index)`, dentro de esta función anónima se
       ejecuta la función setInterval que dentro de ella tiene otra función
       anónima que por cada div que se está iterando y usando su propiedad
       `innerHTML` inserta el valor de la variable `array` (en su indice
       respectivo que se está iterando) sumándole + 1 cada intervalo de
       tiempo de 1 milisegundo.

De esta forma evitamos de buscar cada milisegundo `document.getElementById` que aunque parezca imperceptible estás usando memoria innecesariamente que como mencione antes es una mala práctica.

```js
// var cntr1 = 1
const array = [300, 200, 400]

const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="time"]')

divs.forEach((div, index) => {
  setInterval(() => {
    div.innerHTML = array[index]++;
  }, 1)
})
```

```html
<div id="time0"></div>
<div id="time1"></div>
<div id="time2"></div>
```

Comment: Tu respuesta sería mejor si incluyeras una breve descripción de los características que has incluido en tu código que no están incluidas en el código del AP.

Answer (score 0):

Como se mencionó en la [respuesta previa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/280522/65) un problema del código, de hecho podríamos decir que es el problema principal, es que el código está sobre escribiendo la variable `x`. Para que funcione el código la segunda declaración no se requiere en este caso en el sentido de asignar el id del proceso que devuelve `setInterval` a una variable pues en el código de la pregunta no se usa.

Otro problema es que estás usando el valor del iterador `index` como el incremento a realizarse en cada intervalo siendo que el valor inicial de este es 0.

Los cambios mínimos a realizar en el código de la pregunta podrían ser

1. Eliminar el segundo `var x =`
2. Cambiar `+= index` por `+= Math.max(1,index)`

```js
var cntr1 = 1;
var x = [300, 200, 400];
for (let index = 1; index <= x.length; index++) {
  setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("time" + index).innerHTML = x[index] += Math.max(1,index);
  }, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="time0"></div>
<div id="time1"></div>
<div id="time2"></div>
```

---

Referencias

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval